# Last two mass emails have failed to go out

Tags: email, cron-job, configuration

The error message says something about configuration and “cron job”. I have never managed our organizations emails so I am clueless about how to fix the problem. Talk to me like a 5 year old. Our tech person is currently out of commission.

Comment: Unfortunately cron and email admin is a bit complicated even for a 6 or 7 year-old. It varies widely depending on your setup. See https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/#choosing-a-method. You can start by looking at Administer - System Settings - Scheduled Jobs and seeing the last time "cron" ran and if there's any more messages there.

Comment: Hi Rachel - if you go to Scheduled Jobs mentioned above, and click on 'more' on far right, you should be able to 'execute now' which should result in all backlogged emails to go out

Answer (score 1):

Without the full error message it is hard to understand what you need to do. I'll try to help with the basics.

Go to Civicrm home page
menu item Administrator > then drop down to > Administration Console > configuration checklist > "From Email Addresses" Click to add from email addresses that you should already have setup and access to through your hosting/domain provider.

Now check your system status: Go to Administrator > Administration Console > System Status and verify that you have only green status on "Cron Running OK" with no warnings. If all green go to Administrator > System Settings > Scheduled Jobs and verify that your mailing jobs are enabled. I recommend you visit the Civicrm Documentation User Guide and search for Cron Jobs to understand what each one does, but enable at minimum "Send Scheduled and Send Reminders."

Now test and see if you can send the emails with no errors. I hope any of this helps.